# Entity Framework database-first with SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'll try to explain my problem although to be honest I can't even understand it. After many changes in a couple of tables in my DB now I try to create a Foreign key and I'm getting this error when updating the EDMX.

> gHOP.msl(410,10) : error 3007: Problem in Mapping Fragments starting at lines 410,
>   1511: Non-Primary-Key column(s) [UserGUID] are being mapped in both fragments to different conceptual side properties - data
>   inconsistency is possible because the corresponding conceptual side
>   properties can be independently modified.
>
> gHOP.msl(1511,6) : error 3012: Problem in Mapping Fragments starting at lines 410, 1511: Data loss is possible in Itinerary.UserGUID.
>   An Entity with Key (PK) will not round-trip when:
>   (PK does NOT play Role 'Itinerary' in AssociationSet 'FK_Itinerary_Users' AND PK is in 'Itinerary' EntitySet)
>
> gHOP.msl(410,10) : error 3012: Problem in Mapping Fragments starting at lines 410, 1511: Data loss is possible in Itinerary.UserGUID.
>   An Entity with Key (PK) will not round-trip when:
>   (PK is in 'Itinerary' EntitySet AND PK does NOT play Role 'Itinerary' in AssociationSet 'FK_Itinerary_Users' AND Entity.UserGUID
>   is not NULL)

Honestly, it's been a nightmare because I can't understand what's going on. Although I've given up and I won't create the FK if someone could at least give me a hint I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: it seems wrong/non-primary-key columns are mapped as foreign key in a relationship. For relationship 'FK_Itinerary_Users', can you confirm one end is Primary key of a table?

Comment: Yes, UserGUID is PK im the Users table

Comment: can you give more details about table structure and PK and columns participating in foreignkey relation?

Comment: It seems to be quite straightforward , the UserGUID is the primary key in the USERS table and just a normal column in ITINERARY. Theres no other foreign key in the USERS there's one in the ITINERARY but not referred to the UserGUID column. The only problem I can only think is that there's another table, called EXtranetUsers with a UserGUID property, but I've changed the name and it didn't work. It may be an old problem, having not created properly the keys at first instance I guess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure how much access/control you have over the model but I've encountered similar issues before when updating entities in the db and then attempting to update the model. I usually just delete the entities from the model which you edited in the db! Rebuild without them. Then re-add them after the build. I find that Visual Studio is not always successful updating the model when structural/relational changes have been made in the db.

Comment: Thanks daveL, I have tried this and it builds and runs but after again I can't add the FK. I'll work it around just with the LINQ expressions in the code. I agree with you in regards to VS and the changes in the model